# How to Add Javascript Only When a Function Exists?

Tags: javascript, conditional-content

I have a few function. For both of them need javascript code. I need to add javascript code in header only when function is active. At this time I have all my javascript code in header for all my function and newermind which one of them is active. I tried to make this code but nothing is changed:
All I have in 
**scripts.php**

```
function my_scripts() {
  if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', 
      get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/custom.js', 
      array( 'jquery' ), 
      '', 
      true );
    if (is_front_page()) {
      if (function_exists('function_one'))
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery1',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.plugin.js', 
          array( 'jquery' ));
      else if (function_exists('function_two'))
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery2',          
          get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.plugin2.js', 
          array( 'jquery' ));
      else if (function_exists('function_three'))
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery3',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.plugin3.js', 
          array( 'jquery' )); 
    }
  }
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

**mycode.php**
This code include all my three functions. Looks like:

```
function function_one() { ?>
  ...code.. 
<?php }

function function_two() { ?>
  ...code.. 
<?php }

function function_three() { ?>
  ...code.. 
<?php }
```

This two files are defined in `functions.php`.

I'm new in php, please help me how should I need to do? Thank you!

---

**UPDATE**

Function for choosing slider's looks like this

```
function sliders {
  $sliders = get_option('src_switcher'); // array in theme options with sliders name
  if($sliders == 'First slider') {
    function_one();
  }
  if($sliders == 'Second slider') {
    function_two();
  }
  if($sliders == 'Third slider') {
    function_three();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Denis Belousov - Where are those functions declared?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - This function is declared in another file, not in this. This file is just for scripts only. Bit of code that I show is a part of function that register all my javascript. With this function all is fine, problem with this bit of code. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: @Denis Belousov - Yes, but how do I know from this code whether or not the functions you refer to have been required/included or not? I don't, which is why I asked because it affects the return value of `function_exists ()`. *(You did way you were new to PHP, right? Sometimes we ask questions because we know PHP and thus know we need to ask. :)*

Comment: @MikeSchinkel- I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I update my post with more info.

Comment: @Denis Belousov - Thanks. Your update gave me the info I needed. Given what you have you've defined all functions so your `function_exists()` calls will always return true.  Can you update your example to explain your use-case instead of using abstract names like `'function_one'` so I can understand what you are actually trying to do? *(Often people ask the wrong question and understanding your goal helps us understand how to answer.)*

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - In all my function is markup for sliders. Three sliders, three functions. Each slider have it's own javascript plugin. When I choose slider I want to see only one javascript in the site head which is required for this slider.

Comment: @Denis Belousov How do you choose slider?

Comment: @Rarst - For this purpose I made functions that select the sliders from the theme options.Function is too simple. See my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@Denis Belousov:**

Okay, based on your responses I'm going to ask why tie it to the function existing, why not just test the return value of `get_option('src_switcher')` like this?

```
function my_scripts() {
  if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', 
      get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/custom.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ), 
        '', 
        true );
    if (is_front_page()) {
      $sliders = get_option('src_switcher'); 
      if ($sliders == 'First slider') 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery1',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.plugin.js', 
          array( 'jquery' ));
      else if ($sliders == 'Second slider') 
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery2',          
          get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.plugin2.js', 
          array( 'jquery' ));
      else if ($sliders == 'Third slider') 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery3',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.plugin3.js', 
          array( 'jquery' )); 
    }
  }
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

Alternately if you must use the function testing you'll want the code that defines your functions to look like this:

```
$sliders = get_option('src_switcher'); 
if ($sliders == 'First slider') 
  function function_one() {
    ...code.. 
  }
else if($sliders == 'Second slider') 
  function function_two() {
    ...code.. 
  }
else if($sliders == 'Third slider') 
  function function_three() {
    ...code.. 
  }
```

Comment: Ohhh, it's a good idea. I tried this method few days ago but instead `$sliders = get_option('src_switcher')` I used `global $sliders` and nothing. Thank you, this work.

Comment: @Denis Belousov - You are welcome. Please remember to vote up all good answers here on WordPress Answers and also to select the best answer when you've gotten a good answer to your question(s). FYI, doing so will motivate the people here to continue to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your approach fails because `function_exist()` simply check for function definition. It doesn't care if function is ever run or anything like that.

In your case I think it makes sense to handle enqueue in same way as your slider choice, something like this:

```
$sliders = get_option('src_switcher');

if($sliders == 'First slider')
    $plugin = 'jquery.plugin.js';

elseif($sliders == 'Second slider')
    $plugin = 'jquery.plugin2.js';

elseif($sliders == 'Third slider')
    $plugin = 'jquery.plugin3.js';

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-slider', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/'.$plugin , array( 'jquery' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your logic...

You say that you have 3 functions defined in a file.

```
if(condition_1_true)      // in your case it is
  execute_function_1

elseif(condition_2_true)  // this one is true also, but never gets executed because first one was true too
  execute_function_2

elseif(condition_3_true)  // same here
  execute_function_3
```

So remove "else", use "if". And what's the point of using function_exists() if you know you have 3 functions somewhere in your app?

Comment: At first I've use only "if", but on another forum someone tell me that I should use "elseif". In both case nothing. What's your advice instead function_exists()?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Amoeba - see my comment above.